# Quirks mode and standard mode

Tags: html, css, quirks-mode

When web site is created using HTML 5 and CSS 3 and of course `<!DOCTYPE html>`, does it mean that my code should match to the html 5 and css 3 standard. But how to handle Quirks mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you give `<!DOCTYPE html>`, I dont think the website will fall into quirks mode.